# What is the regexp for the space between two letters of a same word in Ruby

Tags: regex, ruby

The code executes well but I am missing a spec: the space between letters of the same word must be replaced by an empty space in morse. For example: hi in morse would be .... .. (4 dots, space, 2 dots)....the code is not recognizing the way I am representing this separation in my master hash --> "" => " "

Any thoughts on what am I missing?. Thanks

My code is as follows:

```
MASTER = { "A" => ".-",
           "B" => "-...",
           "C" => "-.-.",
           "D" => "-..",
           "E" => ".",
           "F" => "..-.",
           "G" => "--.",
           "H" => "....",
           "I" => "..",
           "J" => ".---",
           "K" => "-.-",
           "L" => ".-..",
           "M" => "--",
           "N" => "-.",
           "O" => "---",
           "P" => ".--.",
           "Q" => "--.-",
           "R" => ".-.",
           "S" => "...",
           "T" => "-",
           "U" => "..-",
           "V" => "...-",
           "W" => ".--",
           "X" => "-..-",
           "Y" => "-.--",
           "Z" => "--..",
           " " => "|",
           "a" => ".-",
           "b" => "-...",
           "c" => "-.-.",
           "d" => "-..",
           "e" => ".",
           "f" => "..-.",
           "g" => "--.",
           "h" => "....",
           "i" => "..",
           "j" => ".---",
           "k" => "-.-",
           "l" => ".-..",
           "m" => "--",
           "n" => "-.",
           "o" => "---",
           "p" => ".--.",
           "q" => "--.-",
           "r" => ".-.",
           "s" => "...",
           "t" => "-",
           "u" => "..-",
           "v" => "...-",
           "w" => ".--",
           "x" => "-..-",
           "y" => "-.--",
           "z" => "--..",
           "," => " ",
           ""  => " ",
           "'" => " " }

def encode(text)
  # TODO: write a method which returns the morse sentence for the given text
  # NOTE: you may want to extract a `encode_word` method
  encode_word = ""
  text.chars.each { |element| encode_word << element.gsub(/(\w|\W)/, MASTER) }
  encode_word
end
```

Comment: You've fallen into the trap of asking how a particular approach you have taken to solving the problem (here a regular expression you have constructed) can be modified to solve your problem rather than just asking how the problem can best be solved. It is so common that it has been given a name: [The X-Y Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem#:~:text=The%20XY%20problem%20is%20a,root%20problem%20itself%20(X).). If you simply asked for suggestion about how to solve the problem you would get more useful and varied answers...

Comment: A common problem with SO questions is that askers rush into their coding problems without first clearly stating the problem they are trying to solve. Readers can only help if they have a good understanding of the problem. You should always begin your question with a statement of your problem in words. Then provide one or more examples (showing the desired result for each) if you think that would help readers understand the question and/or test solutions they develop. Only then should you present and discuss the code you have tried...

Comment: ...Lastly, make clear what you are asking of the reader. Address any questions readers have about the problem by editing the question rather than by elaborating in comments. Questions should be self-contained, in part because not all readers read all comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `master` be the hash given in the question.

Suppose

```
text = "Little Miss Muffet"
```

We can modify `text` as follows.

```
text.gsub(/.(?=(.))?/) do |c|
  MASTER[c] + ((c != ' ' && $1 && $1 != ' ') ? ' ' : '')
end
  #=> ".-.. .. - - .-.. .|-- .. ... ...|-- ..- ..-. ..-. . -"
```

See [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.3/String.html#method-i-gsub).

---

The regular expression has the following elements.

```
.       # match any character (other than a line terminator)
(?=     # begin a positive lookahead
  (.)   # match any character and save it to capture group 1
)?      # end the positive lookahead and make it optional
```

If the first character matched is followed by another character the positive lookahead will be executed and the following character will be saved to capture group 1 and held by the global variable `$1`.

The forward lookahead will not be executed if the first character matched is the last character in the string. In this case `$1 #=> nil`.

---

The expression

```
c != ' ' && $1 && $1 != ' '
```

reads, "The character matched (`'c'`) is neither a space nor is the last character of the string (`$1`) and the following character is not a space (`$1 != ' '`)".

---

Note that this approach manipulates the string directly, rather than breaking it into words, converting each word to array of letters, manipulate those arrays and then converting the result back to a string.

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback!.. One comment though...the space between words is not replaced by | as per my master hash...in MASTER an empty space must be replaced by a |. --> " " => "|" –

Comment: Great input, Cary!!....one thing that I've noticed is that commas and single quotes are not been removed/replaced...although they are both in the MASTER hash. Any thoughts on that?. I'll give it a try to fix that anyways. Many thanks!

Comment: I cannot reproduce that problem. If `c = ","` or `c = "'"`, `MASTER[c] + ((c != ' ' && $1 && $1 != ' ') ? ' ' : '') #=> " "`.

Comment: ...and if `text = "Little, Miss' Muffet"`, then the expression above returns `".-.. .. - - .-.. .  |-- .. ... ...  |-- ..- ..-. ..-. . -"`.

Answer (score 2):

Split the text by space (or perhaps any whitespace) into words, translate each character in those words using your morse code substitution table and then join everything back together (join chars with a space, words with a pipe). Something like

```
def encode(text)
  text.split(" ").map do |word|
    word.each_char.map do |char|
      MASTER[char]
    end.join(" ")
  end.join("|")
end
```

Note

- this will start to fail as soon as you have input that is not contained in your morse table. E.g. a an `é` will cause an error.
- Since upper/lowercase is the same in morse, you can drop half the table and make sure you lookup with the correct case. E.g. drop lower case and do lookup like this `MASTER[char.upcase]`

Comment: Many thanks Pascal, although your proposed solves the overall challenge, I would like to know what I am missing on my proposed solution. It's just 3 lines of code...I feel it could be efficient. Any thoughts would be appreciated!.

Answer (score 2):

Code

First let us get the hash equivalent from the hash using `word.chars.map { |letter| MASTER[letter] }` and then we use this regular expression `/(?<=\w) (?=\w)/` to replace the empty space.

```
def encode(text)
  text.gsub(/\w+/) do |word|
    word.chars.map { |letter| MASTER[letter] }.join("").gsub(/(?<=\w) (?=\w)/, "")
  end
end
```

Example input

```
text = "hello world"
p encode(text)
```

Output

```
"......-...-..--- .-----.-..-..-.."
```

Comment: Many thanks Rajagolapan!!...so that us how the lookahead and lookbehind tool is used!!...you have schooled me big time!

Comment: One comment though...the space between Hello and world is not replaced by | as per my master hash...in MASTER an empty space must be replaced by a |. --> " " => "|"